# How can I add an ID to a password==prompt?

Tags: html, alert

I want to add an ID to the password=prompt itself. But how do I do that?

```js
password=prompt('text' ,'');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216107/discussion-on-question-by-max-how-can-i-add-an-id-to-a-passwordprompt).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an `alert` before the web is loaded, you can link the script folder in the `head` tag and create a function to display an alert.